# Can you track PayPal purchases across sites?

Tags: ecommerce, tracking, paypal, affiliate

Basically, I want to sell stuff as an affiliate, but I would like to keep the user on my site and do the checkout on my site for usability purposes.

If a user buys something from a shop on my site, and the money is sent to the PayPal of the company I'm an affiliate of, will the company know which site the payment came from?

Are there options for this?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to accept PayPal payment on your site, but use the PayPal email address of the company whom you're an affiliate of to receive the actual payment.

If that's the case, you would need the cooperation of that company to review the "Details" for their sales, in which you can specify your affiliate ID in the item's "Description" or elsewhere. I doubt however that a site with significant sales would want to do that however as it would require manual review, or some programming to track the ID in an exported sales CSV.

Affiliates usually do not accept payment directly on their sites. Instead they link or redirect customers to the company's site you're an affiliate of, who tracks the sale by affiliate ID, or employs a third-party site to do this for them (e.g., `cj.com`).

So in short, I do not think you can expect the company to be able to track purchases made on your site as you indicated.

Comment: the question is about how to do it, not if I can expect a company to agree on this. Thx for the tip though

Comment: I've seen similar questions asked on this site - try searching for those. I don't think there's any solution, other than above. Hope you find one though, or a work-around.

Comment: @user1721135 Did you find the solution you were looking for?

Comment: not in the way i wanted it.